# '...late night' vs. '...late at night' vs '... late in night'

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

Is there any difference?

> Yes, on 23rd, I was working late night ([Example is here](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/answer-sheet/wp/2014/07/27/that-kid-in-class-who-utterly-infuriated-me/))

over

> Yes, on 23rd, I was working late at night ([Example is here](http://www.bradenton.com/2014/07/18/5260530/dade-correctional-institution.html))

over

> Yes, on 23rd, I was working late in night ([Example is here](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/City/Raipur/Hubbies-under-spy-lens/articleshow/39261731.cms) though it's a verdict by someone)

To me, the second one seems better but other two don't seem utterly incorrect. Guide me please.

**Note:** I don't want to get into the nuance of *office environment*. For that sake, the question can be...

> Yes, on 23rd, I was *[any verb+ing]* late night.

Comment: The first [example](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/answer-sheet/wp/2014/07/27/that-kid-in-class-who-utterly-infuriated-me/) you linked to ("I found myself working late night after night in a vain, numbed-out attempt to catch up with the paperwork I’d missed.") is about [working late] [night after night] [in a vain], which is different from your own example ("Yes, on 23rd, I was working late night"). I'd like to suggest reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_%28linguistics%29. Knowing whether a string is a constituent or not could help avoid misinterpreting search results.

Answer (score 2):

*Late night*, or usually written *late-night* is an adjective meaning *happening* or *operating* late at night. See for instance [macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/late-night).

*Late at night* means during some time at night, quite far into it.

So you could describe yourself as a late-night worker (if you do it regularly) or you could simply say you worked *late at night*. This would mean you worked probably after midnight.

Another common expression is *I was working late, one night*, which means you were working *later than usual* (the same way as "he was late" meaning he arrived later than planned), at some point during the night (or evening).

Here *night* is used to mean *evening*, as in "the end of the working day", not *night* as in "when people usually sleep"!

The sentence in your first example gives me the feeling that the writer means indeed just that: she wasn't working late-night (which would indicate she was working after midnight or so), but one evening, she was working later than usual.

Your third version strikes me as Indian English - a turn of phrase like *husbands checking their mobile phones in midnight* may seem odd to speakers of AmE or BrE.
I don't know if the use of *in* instead of *one* or *at* is generally common or accepted in Indian English, but I dare say in AmE and BrE it is probably frowned upon.

Comment: *Yes, on 23rd, I was working late-night* is grammatical, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it means you were probably working on the 24th. You seem to have a job that involves actual night-time activity. It is _not_ the way to say that you stayed late at the office!

Comment: Think that *office* is not at all involved here. For that sake, *Yes, on 23rd, I was [any verb] late night.* Will your entire answer change now? The real question is about *late night, late in night and late at night*. But thanks...I'm changing the title to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think my answer stays completely the same. They have different meanings, you have to pick the one that fits the meaning you want to convey.

Comment: AmE I would say "late into the night".

Comment: "I was working late night" doesn't strike me as grammatical, though "I was working late night after night" is perfectly fine.  *Late-night* with a hyphen would probably only occur attributively, I imagine.